# Microsoft Graphic API permission about send message to 1:1 chat

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to use the Microsoft Graph API to send messages to 1:1 chats.

I follow the steps of [this website](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-daemon/tree/master/msal-client-credential-secret#register-the-client-app-daemon-console) to register a free
Azure AD account and get token.

I use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users API with token to get the ID of my member and me.

But when I use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats to create a chat, I get this result:
[image]

Does this mean I need to register for a business 365 account?

Comment: Yes, Have a look at this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/prepare-your-o365-tenant)  make sure that you have one of the subscription mention. Also follow this to [Enable Teams for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/enable-features-office-365)

Comment: You can also create free Teams developer tenant for development purpose. Follow this [_link_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/prerequisites?tabs=vscode#get-a-free-teams-developer-tenant-optional). Here you can test other Graph APIs and other capabilities too.

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/prepare-your-o365-tenant) make sure that you have one of the subscription mention. Also follow this to [Enable Teams for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/enable-features-office-365)

You can also create free Teams developer tenant for development purpose. Follow this [*link*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/prerequisites?tabs=vscode#get-a-free-teams-developer-tenant-optional). Here you can test other Graph APIs and other capabilities too.

*Try logging into the https://teams.microsoft.com and see what you are getting.*